# Can I make an interface that is a subset of an interface?

Tags: typescript

Given

```
interface foo {
  title: string;
  date: number;
}
```

is it possible to make an interface `bar{}` that contains only `title: string` but is referenced from `foo{}`? For example, if `foo{}` loses `title` there will be a compiler error for `bar{}` until `title` is removed from it as well.

The only alternative I can think of is to make `bar{}` first and then have `foo{}` extend it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Pick<T>`:

```
type bar = Pick<foo, 'title'>
```

Comment: Very cool. Is it possible to do this with multiple properties? Like `type bar = Pick<foo, ['title', 'body', 'whatever]>`

Comment: `type bar = Pick<foo, 'title' | 'date'>`